# Copy & Paste VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the world of VB but I would like to copy data from one tabs on a spreadsheet called Ilog and past this  into another tab on the same spredshhet on a tab called Journal.

When the data is pasted to the new tab I'd normally filter is so Blanks are ommited so I would like to be able to get the VB code to do this automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can get the basic code by recording a macro and examining its source.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what you are asking, but the following code will copy data from a range on sheet llog and paste in journal. Then loop through and delete cells that are blank.

```
Sub test()
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = Worksheets("llog").Range("A1:A8")
 rng.Copy
 Set rng = Worksheets("journal").Range("A1:A8")
 rng.PasteSpecial

 For Each c In Range("A1:A8")
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Delete
    End If
 Next c
 Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the range being copied, you could also go with:

```
Sub test()
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = Worksheets("llog").Range("A1:A8")
 rng.Copy
 Set rng = Worksheets("journal").Range("A1:A8")
 rng.PasteSpecial
 rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete
End Sub
```

which avoids any looping.  If you have a relatively complex range, you may want to look in to using the autofilter and then coping over just the visible rows.

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a command for blank cells. Couldn't remember so just made a quick loop.